# Java Spring Boot PersistenceException (OneToMany)

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am currently trying my hand at Java Spring Boot and would just like to provide some data via API.
Unfortunately, I have not gotten any further for hours if I made a mistake.

Error message:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.acm500.db.CocktailIngredient column: cocktail_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Database structure:

[image]

CocktailIngredient Entity:

```
@Table(name = "cocktail_ingredients")
@Entity
public class CocktailIngredient {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CocktailIngredientId id;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private String amount;

    @Column(name = "amount_ml")
    private String amountMl;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Instant createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Instant updatedAt;
}
```

CocktailIngredientId:

```
@Embeddable
public class CocktailIngredientId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6965389309722862577L;
    @Column(name = "cocktail_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long cocktailId;
    @Column(name = "ingredients_id", nullable = false)
    private Long ingredientsId;
    @Column(name = "strength_id", nullable = false)
    private Long strengthId;
    @Column(name = "orderNo", nullable = false)
    private Integer orderNo;
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Maybe someone has already made this mistake.

Comment: You're repeating the same column name in a table. At least the error message says that.

Comment: But where? And how can i fix that? I dont get it.

Comment: Try to change coctailId in  CoctailIngredientId to something else and run.

Comment: Makes no different

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong. You need to modify column name coctail_id.

Comment: ## Please refer to this link ##
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849692/mapping-issue-for-spring-boot-application-when-joining-tables-for-entities